# proving a differentiable function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and a constant $c>0$ with $f'(x) \geq c$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. is a bijection

Tags: real-analysis

We have a differentiable function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and a constant $c>0$ with $f'(x) \geq c$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Show that $f$ is a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

From Rolle's theorem follows that if $f'(x) \neq 0$  $f$ is injective. Which is the case here so we know that $f$ is injective.

I'm stuck on proving it's surjective.

In the questions before this one I already proved with the mean value theorem that $f(x) \geq f(0)+ cx$ if $x \geq 0$, and that  $f(x) \leq f(0)+ cx$ for all $x \leq 0$

Comment: Take that last thing you've proved. To show that there's an $x$ with $f(x) = A$, first show that there's an $x$ with $f(x) \ge A$, by picking $x > \frac{A - f(0)}{c}$. Then use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Hippalectryon I did, fixed it!

Comment: Another way to look at the problem, from the hypothesis one knows that $f$ is strictly increasing function. Now it shouldn't be hard to prove the bijection of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mean value theorem,

- $f(x) \le cx + f(0)$ for $x<0$.
- $f(x)\ge cx + f(0)$ for $x>0$.

It follows that:

$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \pm \infty$$

Hence by the IVT, $f$ hits every $y\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

From $c>0$ and $f(x) \geq f'(0)+ cx$ for $x \ge 0$ we get

$ \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty$.

From $c>0$ and $f(x) \le  f'(0)+ cx$ for $x \le 0$ we get

$ \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)= -\infty$.

Now we derive , by the intermediate value theorem: $f( \mathbb R)= \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, the image of $f$ is connected. So, if $f$ is not surjective, then the image of $f$ is either bounded above or bounded below. WLOG, suppose that the image of $f$ is bounded above. Then let $y$ be the least upper bound. Now given $c$ such that $f^\prime(x) \geq c$, prove that there must be some $y^\prime \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^\prime(y^\prime) < c$.

*Hint:* Since $f^\prime(x) > 0$ for all $x$, $f$ has to be monotonically increasing. Thus finding such a $y^\prime$ is just about selecting an element large enough in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why wouldn't this $f$ be bounded above? If $f$ would converge to a value, it could still be increasing and be bounded above?

Comment: Right, it could be increasing but the amount by which it is increasing (i.e. $f^\prime(x)$ as $x \to \infty$) would have to converge to zero as $x$ goes to $\infty$. Since $f^\prime(x) > c$ for all $x$ and $c > 0$, this has to be contradicted at some point as you take $x$ to $\infty$.